# Georeferencing PNG against Google maps with OpenLayers plugin

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, png

I am trying to georeference blueprints to the footprint of a building. I'm using the Google Satellite image from the OpenLayers plugin to do this. The blueprints are rotated about 30 degrees. When I run the georeferencer after placing GCP, the blueprints load in vertically, but the rotation doesn't occur...

Why is this?

I figured it would line up the GCPs properly...

Comment: how many GCP? you will need at least for 4 to work the rotation out. You also can create your own .pngw and include rotation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you aren't defining your transformation type correctly, and/or not adding enough control points to use the proper transformation type (ie. you'll need to add more than 2 points to get any rotation).

[From this document](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html#available-transformation-algorithms), I'd say you might want to make sure you have enough control points, and try using the Helmert or Polynomial method - those make sure that there is a rotation instead of just a simple shift.

Comment: Yea, I've got about 30 control points that should be enough... I'm wondering if the blueprints are just too distorted?

Comment: I would check the transformation method you're using...